# Tab bar border showing up under nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a tab bar that I am placing under a Nav Bar.  I notice no border when there is a gap between the views, however when I place them right next to each other, a border line appears.

I'm trying to get rid of that border
[image: gap between views] 
[image: views placed on top of each other]